# LINQ2SQL: If I make changes to DB, how to mirror them in DBML?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

I am using LINQ2SQL in my current project.  I have a quite a lot of tables ~30.  When I create my DBML file I change some of the column names etc for readability.

Recently if I made a change to the table in the underlying Database I just deleted and re-added the table in the DBML file, but this is getting tedious.  How can I mimic any changes to the database in the DBML file? (e.g. new column, drop column, new default constraint etc).

Comment: And what's worse, if there are columns that you need Linq2SQL to NOT write to (like auditing fields (CreatedDate, etc.)), you have to drop them off of the DBML definition after you add them.  And every time you re-add them.  :-(  And you cannot fix that with Views because then you don't get the FKs and relations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, Linq-to-SQL has no update feature - amazing, but unfortunately true.

There's two tools I know of that get around this:

- [PLINQO](http://plinqo.com) is a set of CodeSmith code generation templates which handle DBML generation and offer lots of extra features (like generating one file per db entity) - including updates!
- The [Huagati tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/) offer updates and enforcing naming conventions for DBML and Entity Framework

Marc

Comment: +1 for the Huagati tools. It is well worth the $200 if the target is LINQ2SQL (or EF). I find it a shame M$FT didn't just pay a nominal sum and include this sorely needed tooling in VS2010...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not expecting this to be the correct answer, but I thought I'd chime in anyway.

My approach has been to use the drag-n-drop feature for creating the *initial* DBML file. Then, any changes I make in my DB are also then made, by hand, in either the designer or in the DBML file (as XML) itself. (You can right-click on the DBML file, select Open With, and choose XML editor.) Sometimes it is much easier/faster to work with its XML instead of messing around in the designer.

I would only consider the deleting and re-adding, as you have been doing, if the changes were significant. For adding a new column, however, I'd suggest working directly with the dbml's XML, it's probably faster.

Good luck!

Comment: oh yes, and marc_s does mention some nice alternatives to this (which is perhaps more along the lines of what you were seeking?) I'm just throwing out my "poor man's" solution for posterity/any commentary...

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of tedious! Unless I missed something, you're doing it the right way.

[SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) looks like an interesting alternative, and boasts

> It will also create your database on the fly if you want, altering the schema as you change your object.

Answer (score -1):

As far as free solutions, there are a couple of blunt instruments that mostly move you away from using the O/R Designer: [SQLMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) and [Damien Guard's T4 templates](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/).

There are multiple commercial solutions available that offer a lot more features.

The question you have to ask yourself is: Am I using the right ORM?  LinqToSql has quite a few significant drawbacks, database change handling being only one of them.

[Do not use the Visual Studio 2008 LinqToSql O/R Designer](http://www.capprime.com/software_development_weblog/PermaLink,guid,f1a9b52c-b407-4cbb-9197-4bae289ae11d.aspx)

[The drawbacks of adopting Linq To Sql](http://www.capprime.com/software_development_weblog/PermaLink,guid,78e9dd46-b743-4d10-a541-2593354028ba.aspx)